# Set array value as a object key

Tags: javascript

I found this code what count the repeated elements in array

```js
const a = ['first', 'first', 'second'];
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const current = a[i];
    if (obj[current]) {
        obj[current] += 1
    }else {
        obj[current] = 1
    }
}
console.log(obj)
```

I have problems to figure out how this if statement creates the object. I supose that the main logic is here:

```
 if (obj[current]) {
        obj[current] += 1
    }else {
        obj[current] = 1
 }
```

The if statement chack if in `obj` exists a key, it increase the the number `obj[current] += 1`, but how this code set the value from array as a key, because `obj[current]` output the number, not the key. How  the code set the key for object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear what you mean. This does set each element as a key in the object. Objects map keys to values, or in this case array elements (strings) to a frequency count. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @Jerrinstephen, how this: `obj[current] += 1` set the object? for me is mor expected that something like this should create it: `obj[current]: increment logix`

Answer (score 0):

if the current element in the array `a` does not yet exist in `obj`, then its default value is 1. This rough call stack chart may be helpful

```
i |   a[i]   |    obj
0 | 'first'  | { first: 1 }
1 | 'first'  | { first: 2 }
2 | 'second' | { first: 2, second: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {}

if (obj[current]) {
  obj[current] += 1;
} else {
  obj[current] = 1;
}
```

`obj` is a dictionary structure which is also called [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Dictionary keys might be any type in general programming. But in  javascript  usually string or number types used as dictionary keys. You can get or set value inside dictionary using `obj['key']`. You can also use variables to represent dictionary keys like: `obj[current]`.

```js
const obj = {}
const keyName = 'stack'
obj[keyName] = 'overflow';
console.log(obj); // { "stack": "overflow" }
obj['stack'] = 'exchange';
console.log(obj); // { "stack": "exchange" }
```

The code you mentioned checks if `obj[current]` value is not any of `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` or `false`. Dictionary[key] returns undefined if key is not available in dictionary.

You can also write this part like that:

```js
if (obj[current] !== undefined)
```

So `if (obj[current])` checks if obj dictionary has an key equals to current or not. If the key is available it simply increases value of dictionary item. If the key is not available it puts new item to `obj` dictionary with `current` key and `1` value.

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you misunderstand on this line**

> obj[current] output the **number**, not the **key**. How the code set the key
>   for an object?

So if I add a console inside the for then you can easily see the values of `obj[current]` on each iteration based on `i`, it returns **undefined** when the obj doesn't contain the key(based on your if condition) and when it exists a **number** i.e when `obj[current]` is not equal `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `""` or `null` then you are incrementing it by one.

```js
const a = ['first', 'first', 'second'];
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const current = a[i];
    console.log("When current="+current+" then obj[current]="+obj[current]);
    if (obj[current]) { // when obj[current] not equal undefined, 0, false, "" or null
        obj[current] += 1
    }else {
        obj[current] = 1
    }
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: if `obj[current]` is the number, how `first` and `second ` key is set in the object? Where is the part of the code from `for` statement what is responsable for setting the key?